# Using Redirect 301/302 vs URL shortening service

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, web-development, 302-redirect, url-shorteners

I'm currently developing an aggregator site that will gather information across many many sites, typically this kind of applications put together relevant topics and display different information from many sources in a single place then if you want more details the app do a redirected to the original site content I've been looking at many sites and some of them do a 302 redirect and other a 301.

my question is regarding another variable to the equation, I'd like to use a shortening URL service for this platform like  goo.gl or any other similar service.

under this context, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using this service instead of doing a 302 redirect and track myself the amount of clicks and any other information I can get from the broswer?

Thanks

Comment: I highly recommend rethinking your plans. There are too many of these sites and Google generally does not like them. They are seen as spam or junk sites by and large. Still, if you are going forward with your plans, there is no reason to use a URL shortner. It is not necessary. Just use a link redirection script. You can find one very easily for free. (I am sure.)

Comment: See my answer here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100736/is-google-starting-to-ignore-link-directories-such-as-brownbook